# how to trigger a watcher even when assigned to the same newVal

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

i am using `vue3` with `options api`

as shown in the following `stackbiltz` link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-xvh9fk?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FChild.vue,src%2Fcomponents%2FChild.css)

i have a child-component that contains a `button` that when clicked, the method `refresh` should be invoked. the `refresh()` sets `true` to the `event-emitter` as shown below in the code.
in the parent-component, i bind on the `event-emitter` via `v-model` as shown below in the code so that, as i expect, for every click on the button `refresh` the body of the watched variable `vModel` in the parent-component should be executed.
but what happens is, only for the very first time the button `refresh` is clicked, the watched variable `vModel` in the parent is executed.

to solve this issue, i used `$forceUpdate` but had no effect.

I know that the cause of this behaviour is that in the `refresh()` in the Child-component always sets `true` to `this.compPropsVmodel` without changing the value assigned to it, but i do not know how to solve this issue

**parent-component**:

```
<template>
    <Child
      v-model:vModel="vModel">
    </Child>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './components/Child.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
        return {
          vModel: false,
        };
  },
  components: {
    Child
  },
  watch: {
    vModel(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log('@watch vModel');
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**Child-component**:

```
<template>
    <button
        id="idBtnRefreshCalendar"
        type="button"
        @click="refresh">
        refresh
    </button>
</template>

<script>
let debugTag = 'D.Child.vue::';
let infoTag = 'I.Child.vue::';
let verboseTag = 'V.Child.vue::';
let warnTag = 'W.Child.vue::';
let errorTag = 'E.Child.vue::';
let WTFTag = 'WTF.Child.vue::';
//
export default {
    name: 'Child',
    data() {
        return {
        };
    },
    components: {},
    props: {
        vModel: {
            type: null,
        },
    },
    emits: {
        'update:vModel': null,
    },
    computed: {
        compPropsVModel: {
            get() {
                console.log('get.compPropsVModel:', this.vModel);
                return this.vModel;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log('set.compPropsVModel:', value);
                this.$emit('update:vModel', value);
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        refresh() {
            const msg = JSON.stringify({ msg: verboseTag + 'refresh():'});
            console.log(msg);
            this.compPropsVModel = true;
            this.$forceUpdate();
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You set a value. The watcher see that the value changes and triggers. Then you keep setting the same value. Why would the watcher fire if the same data is set? You can replace the value you emit to a counter that goes up every time and you can see it always fire the watcher.

Comment: Taken from the vue docs: "With the Options API, we can use the watch option to trigger a function **whenever a reactive property changes**"

Comment: Last but not least. You don't need a watcher if you want to execute something every time you set something. Just put that logic in a function that you trigger vs a watcher..

Comment: @Wimanicesir yes, i have thought about the same solution you provided in which i set different value to the vmodel every time the button is pressed, but i wonder (1)why `forceUpdate()` does not work (2)how to solve such situation without resorting to `forceUpdate(), is that ever possible please?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-gjxisx?file=src%2FApp.vue

Comment: Hi, it's unclear what's forceUpdate is supposed to do. You can check that it rerenders Child. You don't need models and watchers for this, as said.

Answer (score 0):

In Vue, `watch` callbacks are ***only*** triggered when the value has changed. The diff-ing is done internally, by Vue. Expecting the callback to be run without changing the value is like expecting an elevator to work as a bus or a blender as a washing machine.

---

To trigger the execution of a parent function (method) from a child, here's what works:

- a) [recommended ] - pass the method down as event (`@someName="parentMethod"`). In child component, add it to `emits`:

```js
export default {
  emits: ['someName']
  // ...
}
```

...and call it using `this.$emit('someName', ...args)`, which will trigger
       `parentMethod(...args)` in parent every single time. No need for `v-model` or `watch`.

- b) [not recommended ] - pass the method down as `prop` (`:someName="parentMethod"`), declare it in child props and call it as `this.someName(...args)`.
  It only works as intended with pure functions - functions which do not rely on current component's state (a.k.a. `data`), computed or methods. That's because when running it in child component you're changing its original context.

---

As an alternative, if, for any reason, you still want to use `v-model` + `watch`, you might want to set `vModel` as `boolean` and keep changing the value:

```js
this.$emit('update:vModel', !this.vModel)
```

But that, IMHO, would be similar to fitting an elevator with wheels, a steering wheel and windows, and using it as a bus.

Answer (score -3):

In parent component

```
<template>
  <Child v-model="vModel"></Child>
</template>

<script>
import Child from './components/Child.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      vModel: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Child
  },
  watch: {
    vModel(newVal, oldVal) {
      console.log('@watch vModel');
      // Check if the value has changed or not
      if (newVal === oldVal) {
        // Execute your logic even if the value is the same
        console.log('Value remains the same but triggering the watcher');
        // Add your logic here that you want to execute even when the value is the same
      } else {
        // Execute your logic when the value changes
        console.log('Value has changed');
        // Add your logic here that you want to execute when the value changes
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

In children component need $emit

```
<template>
  <button id="idBtnRefreshCalendar" type="button" @click="refresh">
    refresh
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Child',
  props: {
    modelValue: Boolean, // This should match the type of your v-model prop in the parent
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'], // This should match the event name you emit
  methods: {
    refresh() {
      this.$emit('update:modelValue', true);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In the parent component's watcher for vModel, the if condition checks if the new value (newVal) is the same as the old value (oldVal). If they're the same, it logs a message indicating that the value remains the same but still triggers the watcher.

This way, you can execute specific logic inside the watcher even when the value remains constant. Adjust the logic in the if and else blocks according to your requirements.

Comment: It only works the first time, because the value changes. All subsequent clicks no longer trigger the `watch` callback.

Comment: Change refresh to `this.$emit('update:modelValue', !this.modelValue)`, as suggested in my answer, if you want it to work every single time. And there is no need to compare the values, Vue does it internally. You might be confusing how Vue works with how Angular works.

Comment: See it not working [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/goofy-gould-lm34jq).